# Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ continuous being Lipschitzian. Prove that the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ continuous being Lipschitzian. Prove that the system

$x'=f(x)\,\,\,\,, \,  x(t_0)=x_0$;

$y'=g(x)y \,\,\,\,, \, y(t_0)=y_0$

has unique solution in any interval where it is defined. You can withdraw
hypothesis of $f$ being Lipschitzian and obtaining the same conclusion?

I'm having trouble finding a method to solve this problem. because I have tried to show that f will be contraction, but this method can put constraints on the domain. Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: So assuming you have a solution, you are to prove uniqueness. What do you know about the Picard-Lindelöf theorem? Or the Grönwall lemma?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to prove or how to apply Picard Lindelöf. Note that the dynamics of $x$ are independent of $y$, and that $y$ is a linear system.

Comment: why are you trying to show that $f$ is a contraction?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, the Cauchy problem
$$
x' = f(x), \quad x(t_0) = x_0
$$
admits a unique global solution $x(t)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

If you define $a(t) := g(x(t))$, the second equation is a linear equation with continuous coefficients (here it is enough $g$ continuous).
Hence the Cauchy problem
$$
y' = a(t) y, \quad y(t_0) = y_0
$$
admits a unique global solution $y(t)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: took me a while to understand why $x$ is globally defined, but yes, since the growth of $f$ is at most linear. Nice.